# Internet Explorer 8 waits until page is completely rendered and javascript is executed

Tags: internet-explorer-8, rendering, page-load-time

We have a pretty big web page with a bunch of javascript. When loading it in Firefox/Chrome, the page gets loaded gradually. First the html that already is received is rendered and shown and then the javascript gets executed.

Internet Explorer 8 however waits until the request is completely received and its javascript executed before it shows. This gives the impression that the application is unresponsive for a short period.

We have one laptop on which IE8 loads the page like Firefox/Chrome and we've been searching for a setting on IE8 to indicate that it doesn't have to wait until all javascript is executed before showing the page or part of it.

Does anyone have a clue if there is such a setting and where it can be found? We checked that the Chrome frame for Internet Explorer is not installed.

**Update:**
For more clarification, as @Thariama points out in the comments I also thought that IE8 always waits to render the entire page but seeing this laptop render it I am pretty sure that it loads the 'Firefox-way'. The laptop had half the RAM and CPU power a comparable desktop had and it looked and feeled faster (because of the rendering).

Comment: Only thing i know is that FF renders all incoming data as soon as possible; IE in former versions ALWAYS waited for the complete receivement of data before rendereing anything (i am wondering why it seemed to work on your laptop with IE8).

Comment: I think without more details on how the page is built-up and what you are doing on it, it's difficult to give any useful answers. The only thing I can think of is that if a page consists of one big table, then IE6 would load the everything before displaying it. I can't recall right now, if IE8 still does the same thing. Is the page in Standards mode?

Comment: @Thariama I was also convinced that this was the case. I saw this laptop rendering the 'Firefox-way' and then wondered if there was some secret setting I had no idea of.

@RoToRa The page is using tables (let's not go there) and is in Standards mode.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue today when trying to determine why IE8 would render incrementally when loading from localhost, but wouldn't when loading from an intranet server.

The fix is to tell IE which rendering engine to use. I prefer to always have it render using the latest engine available.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    ...
```

The reason it was happening is because when loading from localhost IE was rendering with the IE8 engine in standards mode. When loading from the intranet, IE defaulted to rendering in compatibility mode using the IE7 engine. The IE7 engine would pause until the whole table was loaded before rendering, but the IE8 engine would render the table incrementally.

To check which mode IE is in for a particular page, hit F12 to pull up the developer tools, and in the menu area there's a "Browser Mode" which tells you which rendering engine it chose, and "Document Mode" which indicates quirks mode or standards mode.

Answer (score 0):

I was recently tasked with resolving an IE8 page rendering issue in a legacy webapp (without changing much server-side code). I wrapped the largest sections of the page in textarea elements (on the server-side) and used JavaScript to extract their contents, remove the textareas and insert the html where the textarea was... it worked out nicely... it even seems to load faster in modern browsers.

Answer (score -1):

If people use IE and it always does that, they've gotten used to this 'unresponsive' idea, whenever I zap open IE to check for compatibility, I just accept the fact that all pages look 'unresponsive' for a while.

It's part of IE, people that live in ignorance are used to that, they won't click away.

Not as much a solution to your problem, which is probably not there as telling you it's not that much of a problem. I don't think there is a way to give a browser instructions to adjust its rendering model for you though, and there shouldn't be, users should be able to adjust rendering models though, but not sites. Those things are a gateway to virus.

Comment: I was talking about a setting in IE8, controlled by the user.